# Can someone help me with a IF AND ELSE function

Tags: google-sheets-formula

The formula I am having probs with is an "IF AND ELSE", checking with multiple criteria 
Check if cell `A1 >= 10` and cell `A1<=20` if so then return the contents of cell A2,  if not check if `A1 >= 20` and cell A1 `<=30` if so then return the contents of cell B2,  if not check if `A1 >= 30` and cell `A1 <=40` if so then return the contents of cell C2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions overlap so I've changed the "<=" operators to "<" but this works in Excel so might help.

```
=IF(AND(A1>=10,A1<20), A2, IF(AND(A1>=20, A1<30),B2,IF(AND(A1>=30, A1 <40),C2,"Out of range")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should all be on a single line, but I'm going to format it for readability

`IF(AND(A1 >= 10,A1 <= 20),        //If these two things are true
   A2,                           //Then return this value
   IF(AND(A1 >= 20,A1 <= 30),    //Else if these two values are true
     B2,                         //Then return this value
     IF(AND(a1 >= 30,A1 <= 40),  //Else if these two values are true
       C2,                       //Then return this value
       "")                      //Else return something completely different
   )
 )`

That said, I would do it slightly different:

`IF(A1 < 10,        //If it's a value outside what I want
   "",               //return a bad value
   IF(A1 <= 20,      //Else if it's less than 20
     A2              //return A2
     IF(A1 <= 30,    //Else if it's less than 30
       B2,           //return B2
       IF(A1 <= 40,  //Else if it's less than 40
         C2,         //return C2
         "")        //Else return a bad value
     )
   )
)`